# Floating Point Exception of my Excercise (C language)

Tags: c, string, pointers, floating-point-exceptions

I've just made a program that implements a binomial function `(n!/k!*(n-k)!)`.

I can compile my program without any problems but when i scanf the 2 int (n and k), it says "Floating Point Exception".

I've tried many ways to fix it but i can't find the problem because i'm not good with c programming :( I'm learning.
Someone can help me please?
Thank you very much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int factorial( int n ){
    int result;
    if( n == 0 ){
        result = 0;
    } else {
        result = n * factorial((n - 1));
    }
    return result;
}

char *stringa_binomiale(int n, int k){

    char *s;
    s=malloc(sizeof(char)*20);

    int b;

    b = factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*factorial(n-k));

    sprintf(s,"%i su %i fa %i",n ,k ,b);

    return s;
}

int main (void){

    int n;
    int k;
    char *s;
    s=malloc(sizeof(char)*20);

    printf("n:");
    scanf("%i",&n);
    printf("k:");
    scanf("%i",&k);

    s= stringa_binomiale(n,k);
    printf("%s \n", stringa_binomiale(n, k));

    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not related to the problem, but why do you call `stringa_binomiale` twice? Why don't you just print `s` instead of calling it again?

Comment: Yeah, my fault sorry. i've fixed this problem but the problem continue to exist :(

Comment: “floating-point exception” means “integer division by zero”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `factorial` function always returns `0` for any input, because the base case is wrong. Your base case returns `0`, and when you multiply by this you get `0`.

As a result, you're dividing by `0` in `stringa_binomiale`, which causes a floating point exception.

The base case should be `n == 1` and it should return `1`.

Comment: I've fixed the problem, but instead of n==1 and return 1, it works if i use n==0 and return 1. so it work fine :)

Comment: That works, too. The important thing is that you should never return 0.

Answer (score 0):

What could give an FPE? :)

HINT: try to print the outputs of your "factorial" function..

SOLUTION: the "factorial" function always returns 0, and its return is used in a division. n! is 1 if n is 0: change that line and you're fine.

Comment: If you want to use the Socratic method, put it in a comment. Asking another question is not an answer.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but.. I mean, it's so obvious that the question is intended to be rhetorical, and the problem on that function is evident once you look at it twice.

Comment: You should still put that in a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I edit the answer to contain the full solution.. Just a moment

Answer (score 0):

your `factorial` function was always returning `0` and thus dividing by `0` was giving `floating point exception`

the `factorial` function should be

```
int factorial( int n ) {
  int result;
  if( n == 0 ){
    result = 1;
  } else {
    result = n * factorial((n - 1));
  }
  return result;
 }
```

and here is the link http://ideone.com/CTKDyX..

Comment: His malloc usage is correct for C code. This is not a C++ program.

Comment: acutally: s = malloc(20)
in C no cast is needed (better not to put it at all) and sizeof(char) is always 1

Comment: sorry..my bad..i was compiling it in C++

Answer (score 0):

An integer division by zero also gets report as "floating point exception". Don't know why that is, there probably are historical reasons.

If your C compiler is recent enough, you should compile with "-fsanitize=undefined". You'll get runtime messages instead of weird behavior for a lot of C errors, including this one.